# Merge multiple lists in Excel into 1 unique list

Tags: excel

I'm trying to merge multiple lists in excel to create a unique list but excel is saying that the following contains errors. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

{=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(List_1,MATCH(0,IF(ISBLANK(List_1),1,COUNTIF($B$100:B100,List_1)),0)),INDEX(List_2,MATCH(0,IF(ISBLANK(List_2),1,COUNTIF($B$100:B100,List_2)),0))),INDEX(List_3,MATCH(0,IF(ISBLANK(List_3),1,COUNTIF($B$100:B100,List_3)),0)))),INDEX(List_4,MATCH(0,IF(ISBLANK(List_4),1,COUNTIF($B$100:B100,List_4)),0))))),"")}

Comment: As you don't specify any error, I suggest that you break this into individual parts and test each part before trying to make it one single function.

Comment: Thanks when reduced to only include List_1 and List_2 it works but when I attempt to add List_3 and List_4 it doesn't. This formula is working {=IFERROR(IFERROR(INDEX(List_1,MATCH(0,IF(ISBLANK(List_1),1,COUNTIF($B$100:B100,List_1)),0)),INDEX(List_2,MATCH(0,IF(ISBLANK(List_2),1,COUNTIF($B$100:B100,List_2)),0))),"")}. The msg that comes up with the formula that includes List_3 and List_4 just states that the formula entered contains errors...

Comment: So why does list3 fail - test that by itself, same for list4. If they work individually then it is down to how you are combining them together, which also makes me wonder why you have two iferror() functions together.

Comment: When removing the first IFERROR, the true value in the formula only recognizes the first index portion and places the second as the false value. I'm by no means an expert and found the formula that is working online and have attempted to now add List_3 and List_4 without success